# Bamboo script task artifact

Tags: continuous-integration, package, debian, bamboo

I am using Bamboo as a build server. We typically only build maven projects which is really easy with Bamboo.

We are now trying to build debian packages with Bamboo. I am able to build the .deb file just fine, but I would like to be able to use that deb file as an artifact for another task, such as adding it to a reprepro instance. I'm trying to separate the tasks out so I can reuse the "deploy to reprepro" task in all of my other plans.

I can't find a ton of documentation on script tasks other than very simple things. How can I do this? Or are there any plugins that I have missed that will build and deploy a deb for me? Thanks!

Comment: I take it you checked the doc here? http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+Artifact+Sharing+between+Jobs

Comment: Ah. I guess I was confused on the ordering of where you had to define the artifacts. That link was my answer. Do you want to add an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to find further information on Bamboo and Maven artifacts here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO034/Configuring+Artifact+Sharing+between+Jobs